# Problem involving relativistic time

Tags: special-relativity, time, inertial-frames, observers

It is said that a clock on a spaceship runs slower than one kept on earth.
The clock on earth can be taken to be at rest with respect to the events on earth.So, the clock on the spaceship is in motion with respect to the events on earth.Let the time interval between two events on earth be $t_1$ as measured by the clock on earth. Thus, the interval as measured by the clock on the spaceship will be $t_2=t_1/(1-v^2/c^2)^{1/2}$ [ v= speed of spaceship w.r.t. earth and c= speed of light], which makes $t_2>t_1$. So, shouldn't the clock on the spaceship run faster?

Comment: is it possible you have the equation backwards?

Comment: well, all time intervals measured from a frame which is not at rest wrt events, i.e. the 2 events don't take place at the same place in the frame, are improper time intervals. Improper time intervals are larger than proper time intervals. If that knowledge is correct then the equation should be right. right?

Comment: Improper time intervals *of the same proper duration* are larger than proper time intervals, yes. But that's a fancy way of saying that the improper time interval corresponding to the transform of a proper time interval would have a shorter proper duration

Comment: The accepted answer for this question addresses yours as well, I think: [Twin paradox in case of two twins that don't meet](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87602/)

Answer (score 0):

The eqation you state is correct, however your interpretation is a bit off.

As you say the *t's* in the equation are *time intervals* between ticks on the clock. A larger time interval (or period) means less ticks on the space station's clock compared to the earth's clock, thus running slower, as seen by an observer **on earth**.

However an observer in the space station will see the clock on earth running slow compared to the clock in the space station.

[Wikipedia does a pretty good job explaining time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation)

Answer (score -4):

**"So, shouldn't the clock on the spaceship run faster?"**

According to special relativity, the observer on the spaceship will discover that his clock runs faster. This obvious result is fatal for the theory but there are deep psychological reasons (accumulated over the last century) why refutation along this line of argument is impossible.

Comment: I'd say the reasons are more mathematical and observational than psychological. Why do you say that special relativity says the clock runs faster? It doesn't say that. Furthermore, what psychological reasons could there be that inspire students newly learning the subject to not question the theory, if it were so obviously flawed. Furthermore, given the extraordinary amount of fame and wealth that would accompany proving relativity wrong, why would any sane scientist choose to ignore evidence against it? I think it is you who are unable to see the truth of the matter

Comment: "Why do you say that special relativity says the clock runs faster? It doesn't say that."  It says that the observer on the spaceship will see stationary clocks running slower and his own (traveling) clocks running faster.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In the spacecraft frame, clocks on Earth would move slower and vice versa. That's the twin paradox. It has an easy to understand resolution. Look it up. If you still disagree, I'm sure someone can point you to the many other questions on this site where someone disagreed with the twin paradox solution and were corrected

Comment: "given the extraordinary amount of fame and wealth that would accompany proving relativity wrong" No, such people become unpersons:  
http://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/o/orwell/george/o79n/chapter1.4.html 
George Orwell: "Withers, however, was already an unperson. He did not exist : he had never existed."

Comment: I'm not going to ask what an unperson is. All I know is that a successful refutation of relativity would mean prizes and grant money forever for that person or group of people. You think Einstein is a big name? What do you think would happen to the guy that proves him wrong? Famous. Whatever you think, I promise you that a combination of the egos of scientists and the insistence of the scientific method would make it impossible to keep such an obvious refutation of relativity hidden

Comment: "the guy that proves him wrong? Famous" No. He will be the most hated person. End of Einstein would mean end of physics: 
http://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/pdf/files/975547d7-2d00-433a-b7e3-4a09145525ca.pdf 
 Albert Einstein (1954): "I consider it entirely possible that physics cannot be based upon the field concept, that is on continuous structures. Then nothing will remain of my whole castle in the air, including the theory of gravitation, but also nothing of the rest of contemporary physics."

Comment: http://www.rapiddiffusion.com/science/crackpots-bane-science/